# Access and iterate array property of Kendo UI Listview inside the template

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I have a Kendo UI Mobile Listview

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: customers" data-template="customer-template"/>
```

Now I want to access the property of the `customer`  which is an array and iterate it inside the template. something like this

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="customer-template">
    <div>#:CustomerName#</div>
    <div>
         <div>Orders</div>
            #for(x=0;x<customers.orders.lentgh(); x++){#
                <div>customers.orders.[x].OrderId</div>
            #}#

 </div>
```

Obviously, this lines throws an error

```
 #for(x=0;x<customers.orders.lentgh(); x++){#
       <div>customers.orders.[x].OrderId</div>
    #}#
```

Is it possible to access the datasource of the listview inside the template? any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the data source of the list view. The template is given an item from this data source which you can use instead.

There are a few other problems:

1. If `orders` is a JavaScript array you should get its length via the `length` field. It is not a method.
2. The `length` is misspelled.
3. To proper way to get an item from a JavaScript array is `orders[x]` not `orders.[x]`.
4. To output a value in a Kendo UI Template you should use the `#: #` expression.
5. Your list view is created from a `<ul>` but the template is a `<div>`. You cannot nest a `<div>` inside an `<ul>`. You should use a `<li>` instead.
6. The `<ul>` element cannot be self-closed. You need to fully close it - `<ul></ul>`.

I have addressed all those problems in the code snippet below:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: customers" data-template="customer-template"></ul>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="customer-template">
  <li>
     <div>#:CustomerName#</div>
     <div>Orders</div>
     #for(var x=0; x < orders.length; x++){#
            <div># orders[x].OrderId #</div>
     #}#
  </li>
</script>
```

Also here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/aHExUWu/1/edit